# how to show run time and loops per hour

Tags: python, loops, datetime

I have a script which operates gpio's then loops until the loop is broken by a tkinter button, id like to see how many loops its doing per hour. im already able to see how many loops its done with a global variable but cannot work out nor find out how to make it show the current run time and how many loops per hour.. please help..
Here's the MCVE

```
import Tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
from Tkinter import *
import time
import datetime


root.geometry("748x150")
root.title("Countdown Tester")

run_counter = 0

ts = datetime.datetime.now()
tf = datetime.datetime.now()
te = tf - ts


def _1():
    label2["text"] = "1"
    label2.config(bg='orange', fg='black')
    root.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)


def _0():
    label2["text"] = "0"
    label2.config(bg='orange', fg='black')
    root.update_idletasks()
    time.sleep(1)
    global run_counter
    run_counter += 1
    root.update_idletasks()
    label6["text"] = run_counter
    label7["text"] = run_counter# *********** Id like to have the run times per hour listed here
    label8["text"] = te# *********** Id like to have the total run time listed here
    root.update_idletasks()


canvas = Canvas(width=720, height=150, bg='black')
canvas.grid(rowspan=26, columnspan=20, sticky='W,E,N,S')

label2 = Label(root, width=11, font='-weight bold', background='black', foreground='white')
label2.grid(padx=5, pady=10, row=0, column=0, sticky='W,E,N,S')
label6 = Label(root, text=run_counter, width=11, font='-weight bold', background='white', foreground='black')
label6.grid(padx=5, pady=10, row=0, column=1, sticky='W,E,N,S')
label7 = Label(root, text=run_counter, width=11, font='-weight bold', background='white', foreground='black')
label7.grid(padx=5, pady=10, row=1, column=1, sticky='W,E,N,S')
label8 = Label(root, text=te, width=11, font='-weight bold', background='white', foreground='black')
label8.grid(padx=5, pady=10, row=1, column=0, sticky='W,E,N,S')

#root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
#timer()

while 1:
    try:
        _1()
        _0()
        root.update()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break


root.mainloop()
```

for some reason this MCVE reports an error on _1() when quit

Comment: Please edit your code down to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 ive edited to an MCVE, thanks

Comment: ive been able to get the counter working by adding `def timer():
    while 1:
        try:
            tf = datetime.datetime.now()
            label8["text"] = (tf-ts)
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break


t2 = threading.Thread(target=timer)
t2.daemon = True
t2.start() ` but still do not know how to get the loops per hour count, please help